# Joomla 2.5 - custom registration field not remembering values

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Im using custom profile plugin found at http://library.logicsistemi.it/images/joomla/plg_user_testprofile.zip

I have created several fields, both, optional and required and they all work. But there is a tiny problem.

When I enter some value in that custom fields and submit the form it can happen that some fields dont pass validation (which is good). However values entered are cleared and I must fill all the fields from the beggining.

- Demo: http://goo.gl/eH1G2
- Enter some (not all) data under the 'legend' named User Registration
- Enter some (not all) data under the 'legend' named Company
- Informations
- Press Register button
- Error message will pop in.  -
- Data entered in the User Registration will be saved
- Data entered in the Company Informations (which are custom fields)
  will not be saved.
- If all required fields are entered, form will submit data to database
  (which is ok).

I want that data in the Company Informations are saved, so users dont have to type in all over again.

Comment: Same is with plugin from http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your demo is on the template you are using.

For some reason it gives Javascript errors. These errors blocks the Javascript client side validation and your form is submitted with invalid data.

If you want only server side validation you can modify the onContentPrepareData function in your plugin by loading posted information from the user state. To do this you have to permeform a different action when user_id is not set under "Merge the profile data." comment.

I think next week I will write a new tutorial on http://library.logicsistemi.it to explain this. For now try to fix your Javascript code.

Regards